# Cookie only working after clearing browser cache

Tags: asp.net, cookies, browser-cache

I just ran into an issue with my ASP.NET webpage. Cookies weren't working anymore. Any Cookie I was adding, even those at the beginning of the page to debug, were not saved.

I cleared my browser cache and it started working again. Does it sounds like a common problem, because I never experienced it before, and I have no log/clue to understand why cookies where not saved. I'm really worried about the fact it could happen often to any of my users during the next days.

Could it be a bad-designed cookie adder? Because mine is wrapped into a closed .NET DLL so I cannot access it.

[Edit]

Sorry, I edited my title and added the word "only". The problem is that I have a website that ran perfectly for some months, then this morning, I noticed that setting cookies in asp.net was impossible. Cookies were shown as empty. Example: "Mycookie=MyOtherCookie=" Since I have a lot of stuff, like user name, secret session token, etc, in my cookies, the website was just not working. Then clearing the cache brang it back, which is why I'm worried and was searching for people who already ran in a similar situation.

Comment: What are you using to add cookies? Did it ever work before you cleared your cookies? Can you reproduce the problem again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that there was no url rewriting for my domain name, so if I was surfing on domain.com, it could't find my cookie that add been assigned to **www**.domain.com, so it needed to be rewritten for domain.com.

I wrote a rule in IIS, now it works.